# Oracle SQL Select total of each age

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table...

```
USER

USER_ID

USER_AGE
```

I need to get the total users for each age, ex:

```
AGE    COUNT

   1          12

   2          27

   3          5
```

.... etc, all the up to 100

I have no idea how to start, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can start here http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select user_age, count(*) as count 
from users 
group by user_age
```